# Windows PC running automatically after putting to sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hybrid-sleep

So I have Windows 10, and something weird started happening to my PC.
It can't be put into sleep mode it just turning screen black for one second and keep running again, is there anyway I can debug whats happening?
If it's malicious program or just a key was stuck pressed?
Tried turning off PC and it's still happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the results of this command: powercfg -lastwake.  Then open Event viewer, under System, Filter Current Log window, on the “Event sources” drop-down menu, select the “Power-Troubleshooter” option and then click “OK.” Then, check log details and see the Wake source.

Comment: @KateLi Thanks!
I was looking at the event viewer and saw that the wake came from the USB3 connection.
It was a wireless keyboard I forgot about..
It was under some stuff being pressed on some keys.

Thank you so much :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use commands as below to see which wake up the computer:

powercfg -lastwake.

Then open Event viewer, under System, Filter Current Log window, on the “Event sources” drop-down menu, select the “Power-Troubleshooter” option and then click “OK.” Then, check log details and see the Wake source.